# Copy Files Contained in a Text File (MacOS)

Tags: macos, terminal, cat, xargs, cp

I have a text file containing .M4B filenames (including source path). The file names contain spaces and quotes like:

/file/source/Ender's Game.m4b

/file/source/Ender's Shadow.m4b

/file/source/Speaker for the Dead.m4b

I'm trying to pipe the file contents to cp the audiobooks to the same destination using the xargs command:

`cat /path/to/file/filenames.txt | xargs cp {} /destination/folder/ \ ;` 
The first time i ran the command it returned xargs: unterminated quote

I then put quotes around the filenames /file/source/"Ender's Game.m4b" and ran the command and it returned: cp: /file/source/Ender's Game.m4b is not a directory

Using zsh and macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach to overcome quotes' pain could be converting newlines to ascii nuls, then ab-using `xargs -0`:

```bash
cat /path/to/file/filenames.txt | tr '\n' '\000' | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} /destination/folder/
```

Comment: Note: normally, `xargs -L1` (break input into lines instead of words, and run the command for each 1 line) would work for this, but it'd get confused by the apostrophes in some names (it'd treat them as single-quotes). Using null delimiters with `xargs -0` neatly avoids this problem.